# Lua: What is the difference in these variable assignments?

Tags: variables, lua

what is the difference between the variable assignment

```
    local newpos = {}
newpos.x = 1       ----- or --------- newpos[x] = 1
```

i know not what i speak but to me these seem to be the same thing if not similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newpos.x = 1` is the same as `newpos["x"] = 1` that is they both set the value stored at key `string "x"` to `1`.

`newpos[x] = 1` is different. This is set the value stored at key `contents of variable x` to `1`.

[Try it](https://eval.in/138861) and see.

```
local newpos = {}

newpos.x = 1
print(newpos.x, newpos["x"], x, newpos[x])

newpos["x"] = 2
print(newpos.x, newpos["x"], x, newpos[x])

local x = "var"
print(newpos.x, newpos["x"], x, newpos[x])

newpos[x] = 3
print(newpos.x, newpos["x"], x, newpos[x])
```

Results for the above:

```
1   1   nil nil
2   2   nil nil
2   2   var nil
2   2   var 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I always forget about that site though I did almost use codepad .org but decided not to at the last minute.

Comment: Thank you both for that, Etan your help is very much appreciated, I am actually beginning to understand the context of this lua. hjpotter92 that link is something else which i had found that before i went through all of the installing and linking on my actual computer never thought about an online interpretor.